# using Sails.js with skipper-gridfs to upload images to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

It doesn't seem like the documentation page is working on the skipper-gridfs github page and so there is little information on what is required here.

In this code..

```
req.file('avatar')
 .upload({
  adapter: require('skipper-gridfs'),
  uri:'mongodb://jimmy@j1mtr0n1xx@mongo.jimmy.com:27017/coolapp.avatar_uploads'
}, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
  if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
  else return res.ok({
    files: uploadedFiles,
    textParams: req.params.all()
  });
});
```

What is req.file('avatar') referring to?  For instance for me I have a function that downloads an image from API and I would like to save it to MongoDB GridFS.  I just not sure at what point I should pass that in.

Comment: The sails.js gitter room is also a good place to chat and get support: https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Answer (score 0):

'avatar'  is referring to the form's field name which holds the file. For example:

```
<input type="file" name="avatar"/>
```

Comment: What about if I'm posting programmatically?

I'm posting to this url http://localhost:1337/uploadimg?file=labels so for the req.file I chose to use labels.  would this be a correct use?

Comment: that's not a correct use because the file isn't encoded in the query string. The file is encoded into the body of your request. I upload files programatically and the library that I use allows me to specify the fieldname.  What you're looking for is the fieldname inside the body of your request.

Comment: I'm using the request framework to help with this.  It gets my image from a url that I specify and then I pipe it and do a request.post to the rest url that runs the saving of images to gridfs.

here's that snippet. 

.pipe(request.post('http://localhost:1337/uploadimg?file=labels',function(error, response, body)

Comment: You still need to know what the form field name is for the request created by request.pipe. Try inspecting req.body on the controller action that maps to /uploadimg. req.file is part of https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper not part of express or request.

Comment: I got that part taken care of but when i post to it now I see this.  I do have an infinite timeout set too.

events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: EMAXBUFFER: An Upstream (`NOOP_label`) timed out before it was plugged into a receiver. It was still unused after waiting 4500ms. You can configure this timeout by changing the `maxTimeToBuffer` option.

Comment: here's an example of some working code, albeit not with gridfs. https://github.com/sails101/file-uploads/blob/master/api/controllers/FileController.js

Answer (score 0):

'avatar' is key of file which you select to upload. It is in request's body with form-data type.

Comment: I appreciate skipper-gridfs and mongodb database. We can build media server with them instead of saving files on backend's file system. So it is easy to scale, back up and replicate. Because file is saved as chunk, it also supports to stream for videos  and audios.